# Using user_status in conditional with get_users to return existing users

Tags: users

I'm working on a plugin needing to return avatars a specific way. If the user exists in the wp_users table the code is run else a different set of code is run if the user is not in the wp_users table. I cannot use the username_exist and am tinkering now with the idea of using the user_status value of 0.

From the Codex, code is possible to return information based on the user_status

```
$blogusers = get_users('user_status=0');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->user_email . '</li>';
}
```

This returns the email address for the users in the wp_users table.

But I want to use a conditional...

The following works on a local development server in which $id is 1. But not everyone using the plugin will have just this one user id ...

```
if ( $id == '1' ) {
    // echo 'User ID is ' . $id;
    // Do something here
} else {
    // the user is not in WordPress do something cool   
}
```

How can I use the user_status in a conditional to check if the user_status is 0 then do something else run the code the user not being in the WP users table.

In other words, how can I write a conditional to check `user_status = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$blogusers = get_users();
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    if($user->user_status=='0'){
        //do something
    } 
    else{
        // do something else
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that doesn't seem to work. The issue is the `$user->user_status == '0'` isn't allowing the else to run for non WP users.

Comment: @LPH where do you store non wp users? what do you mean by non wp users?

Comment: OK. Turns out I was setting the user_status to 0 in another function. Removed it. Now that code works with simply the `if ($user->user_status == '0')`   Thank you for the help.  Update -- Nope -- Typed too soon. This still doesn't work properly.

Comment: @LPH you can accept the answer if use full.

Comment: @RajeevVyas: Please don't pose a code block without any explanation. Edit your answer and say how the code can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [username_exists](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists)

```
<?php  
       $username = $_POST['username'];

       // Check if username exist in wp_users table.
       if ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
           echo "Username In Use!";
       } else {
           echo "Username Not In Use!";
       }
?>
```